# How do I get the milliseconds from epoc till starting of today's? using swift

Tags: swift, epoch

```swift
var timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval {get}
```

I just hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

TimeInterval Since 1970 returns epoch time in seconds, you can change it to return milliseconds multiplying it by 1000.

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

if you need it to count from start of today you can use calendar method `startOfDay(for: Date)`

---

```
extension Date {
    var startOfDay: Date {
        Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
    var millisecondsSince1970: Int {
        .init(timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

---

```
let millisecondsSince1970 = Date().millisecondsSince1970             // 1604931753291
let startOfDayMsSince1970 = Date().startOfDay.millisecondsSince1970  // 1604890800000
```

Comment: Isn't that the milliseconds for _now_? He wants the milliseconds for "starting of today", which I assume means today 0:00

Comment: Milliseconds he just need to multiply it by 1000:  return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

Comment: I'm not talking about the unit, but the time itself. he wants the epoch distance from "today 0:00", not "today _now_"